# SpringBoot 404 on ModelAndView

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a controller like this:

```
@RestController
public class SecureController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecureController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value={"/secure"},
                    method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getSecure() {
        String str = "Security Area? -- GET";

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            String currentUserName = authentication.getName();
            str = str + " -- " + currentUserName + "\n\n";
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(str, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value={"/secure"},
                    method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> postSecure() {
        String str = "Security Area? -- POST";

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            String currentUserName = authentication.getName();
            str = str + " -- " + currentUserName + "\n\n";
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(str, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value={"/secure/sub"},
                    method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getSecureSub() {
        String str = "Security area subpage -- GET";

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            String currentUserName = authentication.getName();
            str = str + " -- " + currentUserName + "\n\n";
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(str, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value={"/secure/list"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getSecureList() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("listpage.html");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value={"/login"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getLogin(@RequestParam(value="logout", required=false) String logout,
                                 @RequestParam(value="error", required=false) String error) {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("loginpage.html");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

There's a WebSecurity thing like:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/secure/**").fullyAuthenticated()
        .antMatchers("/login").fullyAuthenticated()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").defaultSuccessUrl("/secure/list", true).permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout();
}
```

Which seems to work.

I was testing some security thing... Anyway, when going to the login page, the loginpage.html is rendered just fine. It POSTs to /login and everything works.

Until you try to go to /secure/list. Then it 404s. The route exists, and the listpage.html exists in the same dir as loginpage.html and I know it finds it because if I change the name to list.html it gives me an exception about circular routes.

Anyway, the /secure/sub route works fine. So based on this it appears that there's no problem with the ModelAndView and there's no problem with the subroutes but for some reason when used together, there's a problem.

Why is it giving me a 404?

Some Logs:

```
2017-11-09 17:52:49.865 DEBUG 9020 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2017-11-09 17:52:49.865 DEBUG 9020 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No matching bean found for view name 'listpage.html'
2017-11-09 17:52:49.866 DEBUG 9020 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No matching bean found for view name 'listpage.html.html'
2017-11-09 17:52:49.867 DEBUG 9020 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'listpage.html'; URL [listpage.html]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2017-11-09 17:52:49.868 DEBUG 9020 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'listpage.html'; URL [listpage.html]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-11-09 17:52:49.868 DEBUG 9020 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView            : Forwarding to resource [listpage.html] in InternalResourceView 'listpage.html'
2017-11-09 17:52:49.869 DEBUG 9020 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/secure/listpage.html]
2017-11-09 17:52:49.870 DEBUG 9020 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /secure/listpage.html
2017-11-09 17:52:49.875 DEBUG 9020 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/secure/listpage.html]
2017-11-09 17:52:49.875 DEBUG 9020 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/secure/listpage.html] are [/**]
2017-11-09 17:52:49.875 DEBUG 9020 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/secure/listpage.html] are {}
2017-11-09 17:52:49.875 DEBUG 9020 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/secure/listpage.html] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@7383eae2]]] and 1 interceptor
2017-11-09 17:52:49.876 DEBUG 9020 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for[/secure/listpage.html] is: -1
2017-11-09 17:52:49.878 DEBUG 9020 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-11-09 17:52:49.878 DEBUG 9020 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request


ls src/main/resources/static/
listpage.html  loginpage.html
```

Comment: Can you share the directory structure of the application?

Comment: To me it looks like you need to place the listpage.html in a different directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defined your controller as `@RestController` which cause the error when access the `secure/list` page. My advice was create another controller with `@Controller` annotations instead of `@RestController`.

```
@Controller
public class SecureListController {
    @RequestMapping(value={"/secure/list"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getSecureList() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("listpage.html");
        return modelAndView;
    }    
}
```

Comment: If that were true then why does the /login path work with ModelAndView?

Comment: Oh it's seems because Spring looking your `listpage.html` on `secure` directory, but your `listpage.html` was located on `src/resources/static`. Then try move your `listpage.html` into `src/resources/static/secure`.

Comment: ... this thing is looking for resources relative to the uri and not just "within the classpath"

Comment: Yes, I've small experience with Spring, but seeing your error message `Looking up handler method for path /secure/listpage.html` and `Did not find handler method for [/secure/listpage.html]` would it mean that you need to put `listpage.html` under `secure` directory?

Answer (score 2):

For me adding thymeleaf dependancy solved it.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

method

```
@GetMapping("item")
public ModelAndView getItems() {
    return new ModelAndView("item");
}
```